# Unix script to grep for a particular string in a line

Tags: unix

I have a requirement where i need to read a file which has hostname username and password.

I need to read the hostname and fetch username and password.

machine ftp.test login test1 password test2

I need to read ftp.test from my script and fetch test1 and test2 to do ftp. Could someone please help me doing this.

Comment: Can the password have spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> cat ftp.test | awk -F ' ' '{print $4, $6}'

assuming the format of the file is such `machine ftp.test login test1 password test2`

```
echo "machine ftp.test login test1 password test2" | awk -F ' ' '{print $4, $6}'
test1 test2
```

results into this.

Comment: @pratyasa-mohanty If it worked for you can you mark this answer as correct?

Answer (score -1):

`grep 'machine ftp.test' <filename> | awk '{ print $4, $6}'` will give you the user and password.

Comment: Its a normal unix file which has 770 permission on it.